# How to include a header in a R webscrape request?

Tags: r, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape this page in R from Windows to receive the data on the project displayed there:

```
url <- 'https://disclosures.ifc.org/project-detail/SII/45315/alpha-jwc-ventures-fund-iii-l-p'
```

My first attempt was to use this:

```
download.file(url, method="auto", destfile='IFC1.html')
```

But it doesn't contain the data I see when I visit the page it in my browser. It seems that the data are loaded in later via JSON. However, the following did also not work and resulted in an error:

```
json_download <- jsonlite::fromJSON(getURL(url)) 
Error in function (type, msg, asError = TRUE) : error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

I did a little bit of network analysis with Firefox and found that all the data which I need are probably loaded in from this URL:

```
url2 <- "https://disclosuresservice.ifc.org/api/ProjectAccess/SIIProject?projectId=45315"
```

However, if I open it with the browser, I get an error message. I now believe that I need to send a header to get the data, but after quite a bit of googleing I didn't find out how to do properly do that. I see that getURLContent() includes a header argument, but I don't understand how to use it.

The header which my browser used was this one:

```
GET /api/ProjectAccess/SIIProject?projectId=45315 HTTP/1.1
Host: disclosuresservice.ifc.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Language: de,en-US;q=0.7,en;q=0.3
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Origin: https://disclosures.ifc.org
Connection: keep-alive
Referer: https://disclosures.ifc.org/
Cache-Control: max-age=0
```

I did some webscraping before, but the websites were structured more accessibly and the tutorials which I find online only teach beginner webscraping.

How do I get the data which I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have all the information you're looking for with `jsonlite::fromJSON(url)` using the second url.

This is what's contained in the response for that call

```
> names(response)
 [1] "isLinkedProject"            "LinkedProjectUrl"           "SupportingDocuments"       
 [4] "RelevantProjects"           "ProjectedBoardDate"         "QuickLinks"                
 [7] "SponsorCostLocation"        "DevelopmentImpact"          "Contacts"                  
[10] "RisksMitigation"            "DelayedFields"              "AdditionalProjectAttribute"
[13] "ProjectID"                  "ProjectName"                "ProjectNumber"             
[16] "CompanyName"                "Department"                 "Country"                   
[19] "Region"                     "Industry"                   "Sector"                    
[22] "EnvironmentalCategory"      "Status"                     "StatusId"                  
[25] "DisclosedDate"              "RevisedDisclosedDate"       "LocalDisclosureDate"       
[28] "PreviousEvents"             "ProjectOverView"            "LastUpdatedDate"           
[31] "Disclaimer"                 "DisclaimerId"               "ProductLineId"             
[34] "DocumentType"               "DocumentTypeId"             "ProjectType"               
[37] "ProjectTypeId"              "ProductLine"                "RegionId"                  
[40] "CountryId"                  "IndustryId"                 "SectorId"                  
[43] "EnvironmentalCategoryId"    "Development_Result_Date"    "ProjectLocation"           
[46] "PS1"                        "PS2"                        "PS3"                       
[49] "PS4"                        "PS5"                        "PS6"                       
[52] "PS7"                        "PS8"                        "BCS"                       
[55] "isRevised"                  "HoldingAreaStatus"          "isPublished"               
[58] "Update_Date"                "Development_Result"         "MultiLongitude"            
[61] "MultiLatitude"              "MultiGeoNameId"
```

If you need to include a header for some reason, you can use the `httr` verbs and pass the header in as an argument returned from the `add_header` function.

Comment: Great, that works!
I edited the variable of the second link to url2, so you might change that in your answer to not confuse other readers.